# Update form when another form in a different page (another windows) press command button with PrimeFaces

Tags: java, ajax, primefaces, auto-update

it is possible update a form, when press a command button in another form, but this is in another windows. The example is that i have a materials windows and can be other user with a purchase windows, can i update the form in purchase windows when the command button in the materials windows fired?

Thank in advanced!!

Answer (score 0):

The best way I can think to do this is to use the `<p:poll>` method (see [PrimeFaces - ShowCase: Ajax Poll](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/poll.jsf)). From the second window, you will have to make the window make a call to the central server every few seconds.

Comment: Alternatively, you could use the cross-window messaging feature in JavaScript: http://javascript.info/tutorial/cross-window-messaging-with-postmessage

Comment: Was it successful? You might want to let us know for anyone who stumbles across this question later. :)

Comment: Hi, the project shuts down, so this feature was not implemented, sorry i don't answer because that